# Mockito with functions in Dart

Tags: testing, dart, mockito, flutter, flutter-test

I have a method that I would like to mock, however when I am trying to verify calls of this method. I get an error that says:

```
Used on a non-mockito object
```

Here is the simplified code:

```
test('test',() {
  MockReducer reducer = new MockReducer();
  verify(reducer).called(0);
});

class MockReducer extends Mock {
  call(state, action) => state;
}
```

Why can't I do something like this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you have three problems here:

1. Mockito only works with Classes, not functions (see https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/issues/62). You have some options: create a test implementation of the function, or for `redux.dart`, you can implement the `ReducerClass` (which acts as a `Reducer` function by implementing `call`).
2. You need to verify *methods* being called, not the whole Mock class.
3. You must use `verifyNever` instead of `verify(X).called(0)`.

Working example:

```
class MockReducer extends Mock implements ReducerClass {}

main() {
  test('should be able to mock a reducer', () {
    final reducer = new MockReducer();

    verifyNever(reducer.call(any, any));
  });
}
```

Comment: According to link you provided, I simply created new function that does exactly what I do without Mockito. It seems like the cleanest solution. Thanks!

Comment: You can even remove `.call`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to just create a mocked function to use as onTap on widget test environment, with mockito you can do something like that:

```
abstract class MyFunction {
  void call();
}

class MyFunctionMock extends Mock implements MyFunction {}
```

Test:

```
void main() {
 final mock = MyFunctionMock();
 ...

  // This is inside the the testWidgets callback 
  await tester.pumpWidget(
          widgetToBeTested(
            item: registeredListItem,
            onTap: mock,
          ),
        );

  //Logic to tap the widgetToBeTested

  verify(mock()).called(1);

}
```

Comment: This works! I've trying to use mock functions before in testing environment and this is the easiest, cleanest way to mock and test methods passed to widget via constructor.