# Flutter Mockito verify that callback passed to widget is called

Tags: testing, flutter, dart

I have a widget that takes a callback which is called when a button is pressed. I am trying to test that the callback is correctly invoked by the button.

I've tried mocking a `Function` class:

```dart
class MockCallback extends Mock implements Function {
  call() {}
}
```

Then passing an instance of the mock class to my widget and simulating a tap:

```dart
final mocked = MockCallback();
await tester.pumpWidget(
  MyWidget(myCallback: mocked),
);

final clearButtonFinder = find.byType(IconButton);
await tester.tap(clearButtonFinder);

verify(mocked()).called(1);
```

This results in an error on the `verify` call saying `Used on a non-mockito object`. If I put a print statement inside the mocked `call`, I can see that the tap is indeed calling it.

How can I verify that the callback passed to my widget is getting called once when the button is tapped?

Comment: Here is a solution that worked for me: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67060954/6266336

Answer (score 3):

This is how I solved this problem.

```
class MockCallback {
  int _callCounter = 0;
  void call() {
    _callCounter += 1;
  }

  bool called(int expected) => _callCounter == expected;
  void reset() {
    _callCounter = 0;
  }
}
```

No mockito needed.

Comment: Would be nice if someone could provide an example of how to use it in the test itself

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is not the best solution - use a stream:

```
final callbackCalled = BehaviorSubject<void>.seeded(null);

await tester.pumpWidget(
  MyWidget(myCallback: () { callbackCalled.add(null); }),
);

//... actions to trigger the callback

await expectLater(callbackCalled, emitsInOrder(<void>[null, null]));
```

You can use something meaningful instead of 'void' and 'null'.